# solr schema: org.apache.solr.analysis.StopFilterFactory or solr.StopFilterFactory

Tags: solr

My schema file refers to `solr.StopFilterFactory` however, it seems that this class's actual name is: `org.apache.solr.analysis.StopFilterFactory`. 
Is that correct? If yes, where is that shortcut configured which allows me to use 'solr.StopFilterFactory`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is done programatically, so if you want to delve into the details I would start in [IndexSchema's readSchema()](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/schema/IndexSchema.java) and follow the lead there. You will get to exact place where the substitution is made eventually.